# DeviceOrientationEvent for Adobe Air

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, gyroscope, device-orientation

I'm trying to build a game for iOS using Adobe Air and Flash Builder 4.7, I need to read the gyroscope data to find out what is my alpha rotation value(0-360), I've been searching around for libs and native extensions to use with adobe air, but I'm a bit lost.
Is there any easy way I can get this value on my app?
Something like this guy does here:

[Understanding How the Accelerometer and Gyroscope Work in the Browser](http://joelongstreet.com/2011/08/15/understanding-how-the-accelerometer-and-gyroscope-work-in-the-browser/)

What I would need is an event that would give me an alpha rotation value, or a way to calculate this value using x/y/z and/or pitch/yaw/roll values.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to find device orientation only ???

Answer (score 1):

You can find example code and links to tutorials in the official documentation:

[**flash.sensors.Accelerometer**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/Accelerometer.html)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to find the alpha value using Accelerometer, neither using Gyroscope, but I think I can't do what I want using only accelerometer. Could you try to be more specific please? or maybe show me a way on how to calculate it?